# Need help to JQUERY Ajax my Multidimensional JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

i need to fetched JSON from a webserver API.
Short story this is the JSON structure that come from the webserver :

```
[
    {
        "2017-07-28": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "produk_id": 1,
                "nama_id": 1,
                "jumlah_user_id": 1,
                "harga": "50000",
                "tanggal_efektif": "2017-07-28"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "produk_id": 1,
                "nama_id": 2,
                "jumlah_user_id": 1,
                "harga": "12112121",
                "tanggal_efektif": "2017-07-28"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "produk_id": 1,
                "nama_id": 1,
                "jumlah_user_id": 1,
                "harga": "650000",
                "tanggal_efektif": "2017-07-28"
            }
        ],
        "2017-07-14": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "produk_id": 1,
                "nama_id": 2,
                "jumlah_user_id": 2,
                "harga": "121121",
                "tanggal_efektif": "2017-07-14"
            }
        ],
        "2017-07-27": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "produk_id": 1,
                "nama_id": 1,
                "jumlah_user_id": 1,
                "harga": "600000",
                "tanggal_efektif": "2017-07-27"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and this is my JQUERY AJAX that i write in my client side code :

```
function loadtabelharga(){
    var page = event.target;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'url'+page.data.id,
        dataType: "JSON",
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function(result){
            $.each(result[0], function (index,el) {
                $('#prosesloadingharga').hide();
                console.log("harga paket : " +el.harga+" , id harga paket : "+el.id);
            });
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
            console.log("error",xhr.error);
        }
    });
};
```

why its resulted as undefined in my console.log ? i think there is something to do with the dimensional. Can anyone help me ?
this is a new things that i got a json structured like this, and i think it was the `dates` is called on not `id` and `harga` like what i want.

Thanks

Comment: use 1 more loop to iterate inner array.

Comment: It would look something like `el[0]["2017-07-28"][0].harga`

Comment: `el` is and `array` not `object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example which will help you understand. You have to use one more loop to iterate inner loop.

```js
var data = [
    {
        "2017-07-28": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "produk_id": 1,
                "nama_id": 1,
                "jumlah_user_id": 1,
                "harga": "50000",
                "tanggal_efektif": "2017-07-28"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "produk_id": 1,
                "nama_id": 2,
                "jumlah_user_id": 1,
                "harga": "12112121",
                "tanggal_efektif": "2017-07-28"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "produk_id": 1,
                "nama_id": 1,
                "jumlah_user_id": 1,
                "harga": "650000",
                "tanggal_efektif": "2017-07-28"
            }
        ],
        "2017-07-14": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "produk_id": 1,
                "nama_id": 2,
                "jumlah_user_id": 2,
                "harga": "121121",
                "tanggal_efektif": "2017-07-14"
            }
        ],
        "2017-07-27": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "produk_id": 1,
                "nama_id": 1,
                "jumlah_user_id": 1,
                "harga": "600000",
                "tanggal_efektif": "2017-07-27"
            }
        ]
    }
];

$.each(data[0], function(key, val) {
  $.each(val, function(key1, val1) {
    console.log(val1.harga);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
for(var date in result[0]){
    for(var obj in result[0][date] ){
        var el = result[0][date][obj];
        console.log("harga paket : " +el.harga+" , id harga paket : "+el.id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/79vv97xv/

```js
var data = [
    {
        "2017-07-28": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "produk_id": 1,
                "nama_id": 1,
                "jumlah_user_id": 1,
                "harga": "50000",
                "tanggal_efektif": "2017-07-28"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "produk_id": 1,
                "nama_id": 2,
                "jumlah_user_id": 1,
                "harga": "12112121",
                "tanggal_efektif": "2017-07-28"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "produk_id": 1,
                "nama_id": 1,
                "jumlah_user_id": 1,
                "harga": "650000",
                "tanggal_efektif": "2017-07-28"
            }
        ],
        "2017-07-14": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "produk_id": 1,
                "nama_id": 2,
                "jumlah_user_id": 2,
                "harga": "121121",
                "tanggal_efektif": "2017-07-14"
            }
        ],
        "2017-07-27": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "produk_id": 1,
                "nama_id": 1,
                "jumlah_user_id": 1,
                "harga": "600000",
                "tanggal_efektif": "2017-07-27"
            }
        ]
    }
];

for(var dates in data[0]){
 for(var key in data[0][dates]){
   console.log("Harga: ", data[0][dates][key].harga);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the multidimensional array in a plain object.

```
 var your_stringify_obj=JSON.stringify(your_Multidimensional_Json).
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'url'+page.data.id,
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: your_stringify_obj,
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function(result){
            $.each(result[0], function (index,el) {
                $('#prosesloadingharga').hide();
                console.log("harga paket : " +el.harga+" , id harga paket : "+el.id);
            });
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
            console.log("error",xhr.error);
        }
    });
};
```

Now it should work.

Comment: sry, but what is "your_Multidimensional_Json" ? the json come from the url in $.ajax